# How to understand B=np.reshape(A, (a, a, b)) and reverse back by B[:,:,1]

Tags: python, arrays, reshape

I am quite confused about the following

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[1,2,3],
              [2,3,4],
              [3,4,5]])
```

A is a 3x3 matrix obviously. Now consider

```
B = np.reshape(A, (3, 3, 1))
```

B is

```
array([[[1],
    [2],
    [3]],

   [[2],
    [3],
    [4]],

   [[3],
    [4],
    [5]]])
```

If I want to get A back, just simply do

```
C = B[:,:,0]
```

I am quite confused the trick behind it to get B and C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reshape` takes the numbers from the array in order as a single list of numbers, and reorganizes it to the new shape.  It is quite efficient, because it doesn't have to change the array at all -- just the interpretation.  In this case, three sets of three rows of one column each.

`[:,:,0]` means "take all of the first dimension [3], and all of the second dimension [3] and delete the third dimension", thus taking you back to a 3x3.  Again, that's just changing the interpretation of the same list of 9 numbers.